# Selecting records from various tables having joins and union

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For the sake of ledger report of school students -
How do i get this kind of result :  (for student **id** 100 & **date between** 01-03-2014 and 10-03-2014)

```
+-------------+--------------+----+-------+--------+
| Date[d-m-y] | Particulars  | id | debit | credit |
+-------------+--------------+----+-------+--------+
| 01-03-2014  | Tuition fees | 1  | 50    |        |
| 01-03-2014  | Term fees    | 1  | 200   |        |
| 05-03-2014  | Bus Charges  | 2  | 100   |        |
| 10-03-2014  | Cash         | 5  |       | 350    |
+-------------+--------------+----+-------+--------+
```

by selecting records from following tables:

```
- Table 1 = **fees**  [ id - PK AI ]


+----+--------------+--------+
| id |     term     | amount |
+----+--------------+--------+
| 1  | Tuition fees | 50     |
| 2  | Term fees    | 200    |
| 3  | Bus Charges  | 100    |
| .. | ......       | ...    |
+----+--------------+--------+

- Table 2 = **fees_master** [ id - PK AI ] [ perticular_id - FK ] [fees_id - FK]

+----+---------------+---------+
| id | perticular_id | fees_id |
+----+---------------+---------+
| 1  | 1             | 1       |
| 2  | 1             | 2       |
| 3  | 2             | 3       |
| 4  | 3             | 2       |
| .. | ....          | ...     |
+----+---------------+---------+

- Table 3 = **outward**  [ id - PK AI ] [ studId - FK ] [ particular - FK (from bill table)]   

+----+--------+------------+------------+
| id | studId |    date    | particular |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 100    | 01-03-2014 | 1          |
| 2  | 100    | 05-03-2014 | 2          |
| 3  | 205    | 01-05-2014 | 3          |
| .. | ...    | .....      | ..         |
+----+--------+------------+------------+

- Table 4 = **receipt** [ id - PK AI ] [ studId - FK ]   

+----+--------+------------+------+--------+
| id | studId |    date    | mode | amount |
+----+--------+------------+------+--------+
| 1  | 100    | 10-03-2014 | Cash | 350    |
| .. | ...    | .....      | ..   | ...    |
+----+--------+------------+------+--------+
```

Info:

- outward.date **date**
- fees.term **particulars**
- outward.id **id** or receipt.id **id**
- fees.amount **debit**
- receipt.amount **credit**
- Result should be `ORDER BY date`

I already tried this query

```
SELECT date, term, sub, id, debit, credit
  FROM (SELECT o.date,
               c.term,
               NULL      sub,
               o.id,
               ch.amount debit,
               NULL      credit,
               1         ord
          FROM outward AS o
          LEFT JOIN challan_terms AS c
            ON o.perticular = c.headerId
           AND c.type = 0
          LEFT JOIN challan_header AS ch
            ON ch.id = o.perticular
         WHERE o.studId = 100
           AND o.date >= '2014-01-20'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ow.date, ct.term, ct.amount, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2
          FROM outward AS ow
          LEFT JOIN challan_terms AS ct
            ON ow.perticular = ct.headerId
         WHERE TYPE = 1
           AND ow.studId = 100
        UNION ALL
        SELECT date, MODE, NULL, id, NULL, amount, 3
          FROM receipt
         WHERE studId = 100
           AND date >= '2014-01-20') q
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-20' AND '2014-04-20'
 ORDER BY date, ord
```

But it didn't work as you can see in [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dfd8d/5)

Please have a look on my previous work / question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257247/mysql-query-for-preparing-ledger-report-by-selecting-records-from-multiple-tab)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "do-my-coding-work-for-me" place. **You have to show some effort!** You have to show us that you have tried to solve your problem, and then we will help you with the specific issues you are facing. So, in order to help you get on your way solving this problem, I recommend you [read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @kingkero - I have tried this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dfd8d/5) and faild. Now i am looking for new start..

Comment: @Vikram That is already a good effort! I posted that in your question (+ did a bit of formatting), can you elaborate (in the question - not a comment) where exactly your query failed you?

Comment: doesnt deserve to be downvoted... :)

Comment: @kingkero - I am facing problem when outward transaction take place on same date for same student

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I am not getting actually. How do I get records from Fees table based on fees_id in reference table fees_master while iterating over particular_id ?  
please ask if you don't get what i am trying to say.

Comment: how did you get the id values?

Comment: @Angelo- these Ids are based on outward & receipt table.